# PHP regex to replace links with some tokens

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking at some HTML that has embedded audio-playback links like that:

```
...<input type="button" onclick="return play('filename', 'title');" class="playlink" />...
```

I'm trying to programmatically replace that with tokens in this format:

```
{a:filename:title}
```

But something's not working right. Could someone look at it:

```
<?php

$src = 'aaaaa<input type="button" onclick="return play(\'hellofile\', \'hellotitle\');" class="playlink" />bbbbb';
$t = preg_replace('#<input\ type="button"\ onclick="return play(\'(.*?)\',\ \'(.*?)\');"\ class="playlink"\ />#us', '{a:${1}:${2}}', $src);
echo $t;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

`<input.*?play\('(\w+?)',\s*?'(\w+?)'.*?\/>`
[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/gM8rN6/1).

Capture group 1 contains filename, group 2 contains the title.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

```
$src = 'aaaaa<input type="button" onclick="return play(\'hellofile\', \'hellotitle\');" class="playlink" />bbbbb';
$rgx = '#<input type="button" onclick="return play\(' . "'(.*?)', '(.*?)'" . '\);" class="playlink" />#u';
$t = preg_replace($rgx, '{a:${1}:${2}}', $src);
echo "$t\n";
```